# Start another app directly, without showing the 'Open with..." dialogue?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am wondering if it's possible to start another app with an intent, but directly - without showing the 'Open with..'dialogue.

In my case, I want to open a PDF file from my own application, but using Adobe Reader. This works just fine, but I want to start the reader directly, without displaying 'Open with..'.

When the button is clicked, I want to open Adobe Reader and directly load the file to view it. Is this possible?

Here is the code for my openPDF method

```
public void openPDF(View view) {
    File externalFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Untitled.pdf");
    if (externalFile.exists()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(externalFile);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.adobe.reader");
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        if (activities.size() > 0) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader")`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage(java.lang.String))

Comment: Oh, clean and short. Thanks, a lot! :)

Comment: @Calihog Don't forget to check whether user have installed Adobe Reader in their phone or not. otherwise it will crash